# Laravel 5.3 - jquery ajax (internal server error 500)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to use jquery ajax in laravel5. What actually happens all the time is consolelog giving me an `internal server error 500`. I found some csrf solutions and added them to my code but they didnt help me. Any ideas?

```
$('.takImg').click(function(){
    var photoId = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type     : "POST",
        url      : "/save_like",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
            if (token) {
                return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
            }
        },
        data: {photoId : photoId},
        success : function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
        },
        complete : function(r) {
                console.log(r);
        },
        error:    function(error) {
                console.log(error);
        }
    }); 
});
```

I also added this meta to my head:

```
<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Everything goes through routes:

```
`Route::any('/save_like', 'Controller@saveLike');`
```

To the controller:

```
public function saveLike($photoId){
    DB::update('UPDATE `photo_links` SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE `id` = ?', array($photoId));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the `_token` should be always sent in the http request so you could just add it to the data :

```
$('.takImg').click(function(){
    var photoId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var _token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/save_like",
        data: {_token:_token, photoId:photoId},
        success : function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        },
        complete : function(r) {
            console.log(r);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }); 
});
```

`internal server error 500` mean the problem come from your server what mean in your case here it come from the action `saveLike` in your controller, so my guess is that this problem come from the expression `WHERE`id`= ?` :

```
DB::update('UPDATE `photo_links` SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE `id` = ?', array($photoId));
____________________________________________________________^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're passing an array to `=` and that will cause the issue, try :

```
public function saveLike(){
    $photoId = INPUT::get('photoId');

    DB::update("UPDATE `photo_links` SET likes=likes+1 WHERE `id` = $photoId");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I learned a lot from your answer, however it is still giving me error 500. Thats crazy

Comment: Welcome, try to enable the debug mode to get more information about the problem. under `app/config` set `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),`.

Comment: My debug mode is enabled and I always see error messages but this one in error log isnt very helpful: `Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵    <head>↵        <meta ch…l>↵</div>↵↵            </div>↵    </body>↵</html>", status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}`

Comment: Try to take a look to the 'Preview' output of your request under the browser Network tab.

Comment: Ohh finally I found something there :) `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:`

Comment: Good job, now try to make sure what `console.log(_token)` will return.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130315/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-divhelper11).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
        if (token) {
            return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
        }
    },
```

What happened when there is no token? `beforeSend` won't return anything. Change to this:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
        if (token) {
            return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
        }
        return xhr;
    },
```

Comment: I just added this `beforeSend` with metatag a few minutes ago because people over the internet were saying it helps, but it doesn't :X

Comment: Thank you a lot, unfortunately this still is giving me internal server error 500. Thats so annoying

Answer (score 0):

That's what i use in my app:

```
$("#captcha-gen-button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
          url: "/captcha-ajax",
          method: "POST",
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : '{!! csrf_token() !!}' }
        }).done(function(image) {
          $("#captcha-img-container").html(image);
        });
    });
```